# Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt is not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command

I installed VS 2010. When I click Start ? All
Programs ? Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ? Visual Studio Tools > Command prompt

the prompt appears for 2 seconds and closes immediately on its own.

How to resolve this?

Thanks in adv,

Rgds,
studentofcsharp